# json object comunication android - php

Tags: php, android, web-services, ksoap

i need a way to exchange custom objects between android and php, im using ksoap for communication but i need to know how to encode a class like:

```
"user"
   -name
   -pass
   -Person(Object)
   -SomeArray<SomeObjectType>
```

is there any function/library that allows me to do something like

```
php

    $user = getUser($id);
    return = encode($user);

Android

 User = (User)decode(getUserWS(id));
```

exist something like that? im trying to use `json_encode`, but returns only {} and whit `var_dump` i get a lot of garbage.

some help for a new programmer please? tks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this example](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html) of using gson library to convert between json strings and Java types.

The library page can be [found here](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).